# Making a field un-editable doesn't allow me to pre-populate fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm writing a model called `talk` that has two fields `title` and `slug`. `slug` is a field which I do not wish the user to be able to edit and is pre-populated based on `title`. The model looks like this:

```
class talk(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)
```

In my `admin.py` I have the following:

```
class talkAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}
```

Trying to access the model in the CMS gives me the error `Exception Value: u"Key 'slug' not found in Form"`. If I remove `editable=False` everything works as desired except the user can edit the slug as they see fit.

I would like the slug field to appear in the admin but be greyed out so the user can see the slug, but can not change it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`readonly_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) in the ModelAdmin class, not `editable` in the model.

Comment: I still get the same error using `readonly_fields = ('slug',)` and `slug = models.SlugField()`